# R - nlm and Weibull Maximum Likelihood

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, standard-error, weibull-distribution

Good day, I am working on an assignment where I have to

> Calculate the maximum likelihood estimates of $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ along with their standard erorrs on the basis of an independent and identically distributed sample $x_i$, for $i={1,...,n}$ from a Weibull distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\lambda$.

When using the weibull function I encounter this problem

```
Weibull.MLE(c(1, 1, 24112, 412, 412, 421, 412, 412), c(0.1, 0.6))
```

works fine but when I increase the values to, say

```
Weibull.MLE(c(21412,4124,1241,2412,412,412,3,124,21,51,251,25,12,51),c(1,5.2))
```

I get `NaN`

I read somewhere that if there is a big difference between the magnitude of your sample then the variance of your estimates becomes 0. **And this gives me problems later in my code where I try to find the Hessian, it becomes negative which gives a problem, obviously**

```
solve(fit$hessian)
```

This means I can not calcualte `stand_error <- diag ( solve( fit$hessian))` as the Hessian is supposedly negative. Can it be that some other part of my code doesnt work?

```
    negative_log <- function(theta, y) {
  n <- length(y)
  a <- theta[1]
  l<- theta[2]

  if(a<0 | l<0){
    return(5^30)
  }

  else{                    
    loglik <-  n*(a*log(l)+ log(a)) + (a-1)* sum(log(y)) - (l^a)*sum(y^a)
  }
  return (-loglik)
}
```

And here is my MLE function

```
    MLE <- function (x, theta) {

  min_f <- nlm(negative_log, p=theta, x=x,  hessian = TRUE)


  hessian <- min_f$hessian                              
  estimate <- min_f$estimate     
  stand_error <- sqrt(diag(solve(hessian))) 

  mylist<- list(estimate, stand_error)                                                        


  return(mylist)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try an alternate set of starting conditions? Begin with the method-of-moment estimates of shape/scale. Negative Hessians are usually boundary / unbounded solutions when dealing with decently well behaved likelihoods.